# Javascript - File not downloading in EDGE and IE11

Tags: javascript

My code runs without any errors but it is not downloading the file. The code works perfectly on HTML5 browsers. What can be the issue here? I don't see any popup message.

Response HEader: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Test.pdf

What can I do instead?

```
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: "octet/stream"}));
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            var contentDisposition = response.headers(['content-disposition']);

            if (contentDisposition && contentDisposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;

                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(contentDisposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
                  var filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                  a.download = filename;
                  document.body.appendChild(a);
                  a.click();
                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
```

Comment: @VLAZ sry. Actually the error is not there. It simply doesn't download the file. I will update my code

Comment: @VLAZ I've updated the ticket. All the code runs but doesn't do anything in Edge and IE

Comment: The best option is to use the debugger - insert a breakpoint in the first line and go through the script step by step.